# How to find lost tokens? I staked eos bet tokens from a trust wallet. I played on site where it showed they were staked. Went back and they were gon

Tags: transactions, irreversible, address

I have a transaction number showing the 300 went to another address. Think it mighta been the wrong address. I was staking form trust wallet which is a binance address but I think it mighta sent to an etherium address. Can I reverse that?

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand exactly what you're doing, but you cannot reverse blockchain transactions.

Answer (score 0):

U have to check it out real good . Before u seen . It. U can not get it back . I hate it but that how it go. Maybe one day it will change but now not so.